# SITE_2 The application ‘/’ does not exist IIS error - SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, central-administration

During stopping the service Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application on an App server I haven't been able to get it started. When I try to stop it it gets stucked in
STOPPING and when I try to start it gets stuck in STARTING.

The problem now is some web applications work and some don't. But having a look at the app server I can see a web site stopped with the name SITE_19818... with no binding at all.

On the web server I can see all web sites with bindings including the ones that are not loading/working.

What do I need to:
1) get the Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application to start on both app and web server now its stuck STARTING :)

** I have ran all the powershell stopServerinstance and start commands with no luck.
I keep getting the error the job timer is already being created etc..

2) re- bind the websites back on the web server so I can at least get the web sites working

Thanks in Advance

Comment: how you access the web sites, server name & port number of FQDN? Technically you can access the WebSite from Web server as long as services is running over there? You may need to update the AAM to fix this.also check this one http://sharepointadminwiki.wordpress.com/2013/04/29/microsoft-sharepoint-foundation-web-application-service-stuck-on-starting/

Comment: Thanks Waqa I ran powershell command provisionGlobally to re create the site for now and its working ..but the status is still in starting....